# Law of Total Probability question on Wiki definitions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a question on the definitions and their implications.  The discrete definitions are clear to me but I have questions on the continuous definitions.

The law of total probability is defined (on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)) as:
$$
P(A)=\sum_n P(A\cap B_n)
$$
$$
P(A)=\sum_n P(A\mid B_n)P(B_n)
$$
$$
P(A \mid C) = \sum_n P(A \mid C \cap B_n) P(B_n \mid C)
$$
and the continuous case:
$$
P(A) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(A |X = x) d F_X(x)
$$
$$
P(A) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(A |X = x) f_X(x) dx
$$

**Question**:
The continuous definitions have $dF_X(x)$ as the differential variable.  My suspicion is that $dF_X(x) = f_X(x) dx$ and that the differential variable ($x$ if $dx$ is specified) is not used.  The second continuous definition uses the differential variable $x$.  Is this correct?

**Question**:
For the continuous definitions I'm confused how $P(A|X =x) f_X(x) dx$ is equivalent to the discrete case $P(A | B_n) P(B_n) = P(A \cap B_n)$.  I expected to see $P(A|X = x) f_X(x)$ or $P(A|X = x) P(X = x)$ to cancel out the bottom term leaving the intersection.  Can anyone explain how the continuous definitions result in total probability?

Comment: You are right in that $dF_X(x) = f_X(x)dx$ but not sure what you mean about using and not using $x$.

Comment: First question: yes. This is the Stieltjes integral - for well behaved $g$ (bounded variation), the expression $\int f(x) \ dg(x)$ makes sense. If differentiable, then of course $dg(x) = g'(x)  \ dx $.

Comment: For the second: $P(X=x)=0$ for continuous random variable, so $P(A|X = x) P(X = x)$ would not be correct. $P(A|X = x) f_X(x)$ is indeed the equivalent of $P(A\mid B_n)P(B_n)$, but in the total probability formula you have also a sum, which in continuous case becomes an integral.

Comment: @momo Thanks, found in my notes $P(X=a) = \int_a^a f_X(a) = 0$ so the infinitesimal $da$ is required.